# Scala threading behaviour of Await.result() for concurrent.Future

Tags: multithreading, scala

when using scala.concurrent.Future, I want to understand the exact threading behaviour during runtime of Await.result(). Does it release the thread that processed the statements before the waiting for the Future result? Or is the thread kept in a waiting state, i.e. it's not released for other workloads?

```
val foo = Future(1)

// Option 1
val fooResult = Await.result(foo, Duration.Inf)
...
```

I already read the [Scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) about this topic. Does *blocking* in that context imply that the thread is not released for Await.result()?

Comment: The calling thread will be released when Await.result returns. Which is exactly what you ask for when you call Await.{result/ready}.

Comment: So it is not released when it's calling, but when the called method terminates? And you mean released from the waiting/blocking state, since the tread is blocked and thus cannot be used, right? And the waiting/blocking state starts with the Await.result() call?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.